# How to access a specific index of an array in a mustache template, when that specific index is stored in another variable?

Tags: templates, mustache, mustache.php

Say i have an fruits object i'm passing to a mustache template.

```
fruits = { 0 => {name: apple} }
```

I can do this in the mustache template and all is well

```
fruits.0.name
```

BUT what if that index is another variable like i, how do i access that property?

```
fruits.i.name // does not work
```

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid this with mustache and try to use iterations.
Something like :

```
fruits = [{name: 'apple'}]
```

And the iteration

```
{# fruits}{name}{/ fruits}
```

If fruits is dependent from an id on an other structure you're iterating on, try to include fruits inside that structure.

Hope it helps.